# Noise To Signal Ratio custom loss function in Keras not working

Tags: tensorflow, keras, audio, loss-function

I'm trying to implement a Noise To Signal Ratio loss function in Keras. I translated the code from [this repo](https://github.com/csteinmetz1/auraloss/blob/35eed0f5388101466b49820efa8d18cc26c45f82/auraloss/time.py#L5) that works with torch.
Not sure if the tf.math operations that I used do the same stuff as torch's functions. When training, I keep getting `loss: nan - val_loss: nan`.
What am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

```
def noiseToSignalLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    losses = tf.math.divide(
        tf.math.reduce_sum(
            tf.math.pow(
                tf.math.abs(
                    tf.math.subtract(
                        y_true,
                        y_pred
                    )
                ),
                2
            ),
            axis=-1
        ),
        tf.math.reduce_sum(
            tf.math.pow(tf.math.abs(y_true),2),
            axis=-1
        )
    )
    return tf.reduce_mean(losses, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `axis` parameters were wrong. Here's the working Noise To Signal Ratio loss function for Keras, if anyone is interested:

```
def noiseToSignalLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    losses = tf.math.divide(
        tf.math.reduce_sum(
            tf.math.pow(
                tf.math.abs(
                    tf.math.subtract(
                        y_true,
                        y_pred
                    )
                ),
                2
            )
        ),
        tf.math.reduce_sum(
            tf.math.pow(tf.math.abs(y_true),2)
        )
    )
    return tf.reduce_mean(losses)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried applying your code to some inputs and found that it did work.
I think it is the output of the network (not the loss function) that the cause of nan is.
(For example, the output is nan or `y_true` is so close to zero that dividing by it results in inf.)

Comment: Thanks. I still can't get it to work, tho. Tried different network sizes, optimizers, learning rates, etc. With MSE it runs ok (but gives poor results after trained). :(